# 12.04 vs 14.04 on an old laptop

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, upgrade

I installed 12.04 on an ancient Toshiba laptop several years ago, and it worked quite well.  One of my acquaintances recommended that I upgrade to 14.04.  This I did, but only with great difficulty, and this installation has been very buggy the entire time I've used it. Recently it failed entirely and eventually I gave up on trying to fix it and reinstalled 12.04, which works just fine.

I realize that this is an obsolete installation and will reach its end of life in April,  but since it works for me, is there any compelling reason that I should try upgrading again?

Jim

Comment: Consider xubuntu or lubuntu for resources computers.

Comment: After end-of-life you will no longer receive updates, which might be ok with you however security updates would potentially (depending on your use case) be the biggest reason you would want to undertake an upgrade.

Comment: 12.04 does not reach End of Life until April 26th 2017, enjoy Precise Pangolin until that time :)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you'd find to be “compelling”. Is the complete lack of security relevant software updates enough? Though I guess it doesn't matter if your computer isn't connected directly or indirectly to the internet and you don't install software from unofficial sources and nobody but trusted people access it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using vanilla Ubuntu on very old hardware, I would recommend trying Lubuntu or Xubuntu. They are lightweight distros and should be better suited for your computer.